# Extensible GUI framework for Java

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, overlay, extensible

I'm a fan of swing and find it has done everything I need except for extensible GUIs.  I can make small parts extensible programmatically, but if I want to plug in an optional feature it can be quite tedious to dynamically generate every component being altered.

The short period I spent writing a Firefox plug in got me very interested in the idea of Overlays.

Does there exist anything for Java with a similar concept?

Answer (score 2):

It would of course be good to know more precisely what do you mean by "extensible" GUI.

In my work most needs for extending Swing components are nicely fulfilled by [JXLayer](https://jxlayer.dev.java.net/). For example, things like implementing validation notification layer, blocking with progress indication etc.

Answer (score 1):

> "to plug in"

Do you mean plugins?

Take a look here:
http://karussell.wordpress.com/2009/09/16/plugable-swing-a-hello-world-osgi-example/

similar things are possible with NetBeans lookup class (openide) and the ServiceLoader included in JDK6:
http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2008/08/12/simple-dependency-injection-serviceloader-jdk-6

For an extensible GUI framework look here:
http://karussell.wordpress.com/2009/10/08/java-application-frameworks-not-only-client-side/

Update: Now with [griffon](http://griffon.codehaus.org/) you can do this too

Answer (score 0):

There have been multiple attempts at projects that can [convert an xml document into a java GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321034/java-gui-described-in-xml).

[JavaFX](http://www.javafx.com/) would be ideal, but that requires 1.6u10 or better.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the SwingBean framework.

It's kind of cool, because it allows you to generate user interfaces through xml files.

Here is the link: http://swingbean.sourceforge.net/